# Data Factory V2 Error Code 2200 on Data issue while pulling data from AWS RDS to DataFactory (Azure mysql)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds, azure-data-factory, aws-rds-data-service

I'm using these doc's to configure https://fabriciosanchez-en.azurewebsites.net/copying-data-from-aws-rds-mysql-into-azure-through-data-factory-integration-runtime/ the complete set up was done but when I'm running the pipeline to copy the data this error is coming

I attatched error image here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twuFC.png)

> "ErrorCode=UserErrorAzureMysqlNetConnectionError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=connection
> exception:No certificates were found in the certificate
> store,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.AzureMySqlNetConnector,''Type=MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,Message=No
> certificates were found in the certificate
> store,Source=MySqlConnector,'".

Comment: What options do you have for "SSL Mode"? in the MySQL connector in ADF. Try disabling it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, i disabled the SSL Mode and tried it worked thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> No certificates were found in the certificate

Is an SSL related error. You can try and resolve that or just disable SSL using the option in the MySQL Connector.